# SQL Server Management Studio replacing single quotes with double quotes when modifying stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whenever I attempt to "modify" or use the "script to" function with a stored procedure within SQL Server Management Studio, every single quote in the SP is replaced with a double quote. Whenever any of my colleagues uses modify or script to, they receive the output in single quotes. The double quotes break the query. It appears to be a setting within SSMS, but I cannot find any such setting.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are getting dynamic SQL from the scripting options because you have this option selected:

> Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Check for object existence

When this setting is enabled, the script is generated like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = ...)
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'ALTER PROCEDURE...'
END
```

Disable this option, and it should be correct when you use `right-click > Modify` or `right-click > Script stored procedure as > ALTER to >`.

Comment: I just needed the reverse than what OP posted but the answer remains same. It was just that the option was disabled in my environment and I had to enable it. Thanks for answering :)